# How i can Natural sort in mysql? I have followed table:

Tags: mysql, sorting

How i can Natural sort in mysql? I have followed table:

```
CREATE TABLE sortnum
    (`name` varchar(255))
;

INSERT INTO sortnum
    (`name`)
VALUES
    ('atul'), 
    ('test-2~'), 
    ('Room 1'),  
    ('Room 11'),
    ('Room 2'),
    ('Room 3'),
    ('Room 4'),
    ('Room 1025'),
    ('Room 120'),
    ('Room 998'),
    ('test-1~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:"<>?/.,;][') 
;
```

It would be great if anyone can have solution as it is needed to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your answer this way... enjoy

```
SELECT name, 
CONVERT(REPLACE(name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, REVERSE(CONVERT(REVERSE(name), SIGNED)), 1), ''),SIGNED) as t,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, REVERSE(CONVERT(REVERSE(name), SIGNED)), 1) AS d
FROM sortnum
ORDER BY d, t ASC;
```